# Do I need to update g++ version? If so, then how to do that?

Tags: c++

I am working on mac system.
g++ version is "Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0"(I typed g++ --version).

I need to install a c++ package with command - '    $(COMPILER) $(FLAGS) <file_name>.o output.o -lm -o <file_name>    '

What should I write in the place of     $(FLAGS)?

[This link](https://caiorss.github.io/C-Cpp-Notes/compiler-flags-options.html) says there is no flag for g++-12. Then, should I update the version of g++?

---

P.S.
Thanks who commented.
After reading all those, I tried to reinstall the package.

I know now that g++ version is 11.

I typed - 'g++  -std=c++11 <file_name>.o -lm -o <file_name>'
It worked without any error. There is a file in that folder with the name '<file_name>.o'.

After the installation (without any error) I typed - 'g++ <file1_name>.cpp  -o <file1_name>' I have got an error -

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
...
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

So, what should I do now?

Comment: do files `<file_name>.o` and `output.o` exist? Have you tried `g++ <file_name>.o output.o -lm -o <file_name>`? - assuming you know what <file_name> should be? - what error do you get?

Comment: You're using `Xcode` I guess? If so, you should add the appropriate `tag`. I know it's confusing, but `gcc` and `clang` are completely different compilers, and `Xcode` uses `clang` only - if you use the `gcc` it simply overrides with `clang` command instead of telling you it doesn't support `gcc`.

Comment: [@elliott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8658157/elliott)
Thanks for the reply. I am not using Xcode - I am just using the terminal.

Comment: You probably won't need to update and you're not installing anything there: You're just linking 2 object files and a lib into a binary. If linking fails, you may need to update, but even in that case I'd check the error message first...

Comment: @PoreyS, interesting. I'm not a mac user myself. I'm surprised that even in terminal you're being overridden.

Comment: g++ is clang??? Link a prog vs. install a compiler??? Sorry, but I have really no idea what we are talking about. If the task is simply linking a prog, simply use no flags and show the error messages. More or less you will get some unresolved symbols which can easily be fixed by adding some libraries or some other flags for target specific options like position independent code or something.

Comment: @Klaus, on MacOs, `gcc/g++` are aliases for `clang/clang++`. [This blog explains how it's harder to override this alias than you may think](https://tiendq.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/how-to-install-gcc-on-macos-and-make-it-your-default-c-c-compiler/). I only pointed out that this question is really about `clang`, I didn't try to answer it.

Comment: This is not "installation" in any normal sense of the word, and the instructions look like an introduction to how to compile and link a C++ program. It's quite impossible to help you without more context.

Comment: @molbdnilo: "It's quite impossible to help you without more context" And why you don't vote to close? There is an option for "needs more clarity or details". That help us to improve the overall quality of questions here on SO. Thanks!